# PHP - Does MySQL query won't work if database is in MS SQL Server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I was wondering why `MySQL Query`is not working on my localhost(XAMPP), it was like a simple `LIMIT` and `Offset` clause not working. So I try to check deep on my code and I notice that my `Database` is in a `MS SQL Server`. Now I try to use `TOP` keyword instead of `LIMIT` and it work. My question is does connecting to a `MS SQL Database` wouldn't allow me to use `MySQL query`? If so is there any possible way to use `MySQL query` on my case? Because I'm having a hard time on my query using `SQL Query`. I really need an answer on this, any answers is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Some ANSI compliant SQL keywords work in all databases like `SELECT * FROM table`.. Some databases provide extra non compliant ANSI SQL syntax. . for example select the first 10 rows. MySQL query `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10` ... MSSQL query  `SELECT TOP 10 FROM table ORDER BY id ASC` .. Both queries generate the same results when using the same data but the queries arent SQL ANSI compliant so they only work on the database the SQL queries are designed to work.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Every brand real-world SQL database server system has its own dialect of the query language. It's a rare and carefully crafted query that works cross-brand.

And, pretty much no query with a `LIMIT` or `TOP` clause works cross-brand.

Welcome to the world of full employment for SQL coders!